# Backbone.js: View not being rendered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very basic Backbone view I'm trying to render, but for some reason nothing is showing up on screen. The code is:

```
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'user-list',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log(this.$el.html());  // LOG #1
        this.$el.html('<li>Is this showing up?</li>');
        console.log(this.$el.html());  // LOG #2

    }
});

var userList = new UserList();
userList.render();
```

The first time I log the contents of the `el` it shows nothing, and the second time it has the right contents but nothing appears on screen. Can anyone think of why this would be happening? I know that the render function is firing and that `this` is properly bound to `this.render`. Also, `this.$el` is set to a valid jQuery object (defined in my HTML).

Comment: It seems like it is showing up in the second console call b/c you are setting the value explicitly. Seems like the init function is not setting the value of el at all.

Comment: If I log `this.el` from `render` I do get the right DOM element... is that what you mean? Maybe I'm being dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified an `el` on the view, it's not attached to the DOM anywhere.  You need to explicitly attach it:

```
var userList = new UserList();
$("body").html(userList.render());
```

And also return a value from `render`:

```
render: function () {
    console.log(this.$el.html());  // LOG #1
    this.$el.html('<li>Is this showing up?</li>');
    console.log(this.$el.html());  // LOG #2
    return this.$el;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4B6r2/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was enough to specify the ID... lesson learned.